# Convert List<string> to List<object> in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a list of string that looks something like this:

```
var rawData = new List<string>(){ "EUR/USD;123" , "EUR/GBP;321", "BTC/USD;2321"};
```

I have the following structure:

```
public class Data
{
    public string instrument { get; set; }
    public string positions { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to have a list of the string data, splited on the ';' char and converted to a list of objects.

```
var processedData = new List<Data>();

// processedData[0] ( instrument = EUR/USD, positions = 123 )
// processedData[1] ( instrument = EUR/GBP, positions = 321)
// processedData[2] ( instrument = BTC/USD, positions = 2321)
```

Do you have any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: So what happened when you tried to split the entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *Linq* and *query* `rawData`:

```
var processedData = rawData
  .Select(item => item.Split(';'))
  .Select(items => new Data() {
     instrument = items[0],
     positions  = items[1]
   })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: you can do in one select

Comment: @Power Mouse: Yes, it can be done in one `Select`, I've implemented it with two `Select` in order to have more readable (IMHO) code.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var rawString in rawData){
  var split = rawString.Split(";");

  processedData.Add(new Data(){ 
    instruments = split[0],
    positions = split[1]
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below

```
        private static void TestFunc()
    {
        var rawData = new List<string>() { "EUR/USD;123", "EUR/GBP;321", "BTC/USD;2321" };
        var processedData = new List<Data1>();

        foreach (var item in rawData)
        {
            var ins = item.Split(";")[0];
            var pos = item.Split(";")[1];
            processedData.Add(new Data1(ins, pos));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq

```
void Main()
{
    var rawData = new List<string>() { "EUR/USD;123", "EUR/GBP;321", "BTC/USD;2321" };

    rawData.Select(s => 
            new Data() {instrument= s.Split(";")[0],positions = (s.Split(";").Count() > 1) ? s.Split(";")[1] : null})
        .ToList().Dump();

}

public class Data
{
    public string instrument { get; set; }
    public string positions { get; set; }
}
```

[image]